# Commutative Banach algebras with zero-dimensional maximal ideal space and disjoint supports of Gelfand transforms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-algebras, dimension-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative semi-simple unital Banach algebra and let $\Delta$ be the maximal ideal space of $A$. Denote by $\widehat{\cdot}\colon A\to C(\Delta)$ the Gelfand transform.

If $\Delta$ is zero-dimensional, can we find for any $a,b\in A$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ new elements

- $a^\prime, b^\prime\in A$ such that $\|a-a^\prime\|, \|b-b^\prime\| < \varepsilon$,
- $ab = a^\prime b^\prime$, and
- $\widehat{a^\prime}^{-1}(0) \cap \widehat{b^\prime}^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$?

This is possible when $A = C(\Delta)$ or $A = BV[0,1]$ (the algebra of functions of bounded variation), but not sure otherwise, when the Gelfand transform *shirnks elements too much*. I've tried using the Shilov idempotent theorem, but it gives no control over the norm of the projections in $A$ corresponding to clopen subsets of $\Delta$.

Are there some natural extra assumptions that would make it work?

Comment: Could you give some more detail of why this works for $A=C(\Delta)$?

Comment: @YemonChoi, when two functions are small $|f(x)|, |g(x)|<\varepsilon$, you take a smaller clopen sets that contains zeros of both and put $f' = \varepsilon/2$ on that clopen set and $g' = 2/\varepsilon fg$. On the complement you leave them unchanged.